# How to create app?

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask

I want create app (something similar to cointool) where I can create eth wallet with seeds + I want create multiple address to that account by one click.
Also I want to create option to interact with existing smart contract. (mint xen, claim xen etc) + I want to be able to send tokens from multiple addresses to one wallet.

Could you tel me where I should start? What should I learn? What technologies should I use?
DO you know any tutorial related to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use React/Angular for the front end. I would suggest using EtherJS - https://docs.ethers.org/v5/ to script your app functions and Solidity for your smart contracts.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so general, but for doing this you need one or couple smart contract, so you need solidity, for making your application you can use nextJs,
and for interact with your smart contracts and wallets you can use javascript and ethersJs.
At first make sure how you want do those things that you say and make it clear, it could help you for start writing your app.